# Retrofit & HTTP Patch

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, patch, retrofit

So I want to make a PATCH request using Retrofit but currently I cannot add okhttp to my classpath. When I attempt to make a PATCH request I get the stack trace below. Is there any other way I could use Patch without using okhttp?

```
    java.net.ProtocolException
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:644)
        at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:50)
        at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:37)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:358)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:264)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:315)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-09 10:53:09.349    1809-1897/**.****.****** D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of `HttpUrlConnection`. You can either use Apache or OkHttp which both support `PATCH` as an alternative client. This can be done explicitly in the builder:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(..)
    .setClient(new OkClient())
    .build()
```

Additionally, some servers allow specifying an `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header for changing the method. With this you would send a `POST` but include `PATCH` as this header value. Again, this requires server support.

Finally, one other option would be to subclass Retrofit's `UrlConnectionClient` and use reflection to change the field which holds the HTTP method. This is very fragile, prone to future breakage, and is the worst option in my opinion.