# PATCH Verb in Android (OkHttp, Volley, Retrofit...)

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

I know a similar question has been asked a few times now, but I can't seem to find a solution for a simple problem: `PATCH` verb.

So I ask anyone who as solved the PATCH issue in Android either by using OkHttp, Volley or Retrofit ( or if you used a different method or library, please share).

I have spent 3 days digging around and I can't find any solutions to this problem.  All I am trying to do is to do a partial update to a table via RESTful API which is built and ran in .NET environment.

I am currently using Volley, but every time I run the app, I get the exception error that says something along the lines of `PATCH is not an allowed...?` and it then gives a array of other verbs that can be used such as "POST, PUT, GET...".  So, not very helpful at all.

I have tried using `OkHttp` like this:

```
  JSONObject infoRequestBody = new JSONObject();


    try {


        infoRequestBody.put("Salutation", "MRrr.");
        infoRequestBody.put("FirstName", "Work Now!!");
        infoRequestBody.put("LastName", "Test from my mobile again!! Okhttp");
        infoRequestBody.put("MiddleName", "From the Mobile");
        infoRequestBody.put("NickName", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("BirthDate", "1978-11-23T00:00:00.000Z");
        infoRequestBody.put("CompanyName", null);
        // infoRequestBody.put("RegDate", "2015-01-18T23:39:13.873Z");
        infoRequestBody.put("Gender", "Male");
        infoRequestBody.put("IsPregnant", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("IsNursing", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("WorkPhone", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("WorkPhoneExt", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("PhoneNumber", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("Address", "My android app working!!");
        infoRequestBody.put("Address2", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("City", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("State", "CA");
        infoRequestBody.put("ZipCode", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("EmailAddress", "email@me.com");
        infoRequestBody.put("Occupation", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("CountryofResidence", "United States");
        infoRequestBody.put("CountryCode", "US");
        infoRequestBody.put("Ethnicity", "Asian");
        infoRequestBody.put("ModifiedDate", "2015-01-18T23:39:13.873Z");
        infoRequestBody.put("ModifiedBy", null);
        infoRequestBody.put("AcceptedTerms", true);
        infoRequestBody.put("AcceptedPrivacyPolicyCheckbox", false);
        infoRequestBody.put("AcceptedUnder18ConsentCheckbox", false);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  RequestBody body = com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody.create(JSON, infoRequestBody.toString());


    com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder request = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder()
             .url("APIUrls.PATIENT_INFO_URL")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", APIUrls.ZUMO_KEY)
            .patch(body);



    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {




        @Override
        public void onFailure(com.squareup.okhttp.Request request, IOException e) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(com.squareup.okhttp.Response response) throws IOException {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code" + response);

            Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
            for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
            }


            System.out.println(response.body().string());

        }
    });
```

but `client.newCall(request).enque(new Callback()...` gives me an error saying that the `request` can not be applied to `Request.Builder`.

I am new to OkHttp, by the way.

Anyways,  I have been struggling to get `PATCH` to work for far too long.  Maybe I am shooting in the dark, but if anyone out there has any suggestions, thoughts on how to get 'PATCH` to work, I'd be forever grateful to you.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're missing a call to `.build()` after `.patch()`. You want a `Request`, not a `Request.Builder`.

Comment: Have you tried using a REST client like Rested, one of the many chrome extensions, etc, to make sure the request is supported by your server?

Comment: @JacobTabak, yes I have.  It all works fine, except when I try to do the same in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! Thanks @Adam and everyone who contributed to get me in the right direction.  Really appreciate it.  So, here's what I ended up doing (I barely customized what @Adam posted, which of course is the correct answer!):

Firstly,

I set up my `UserUpdate` class as follows:

```
public class UserUpdate {
public String Salutation;
public String FirstName;
public String LastName;
public String MiddleName;
public String NickName;

     //Setters and Getters...
  public String getSalutation() {
      return Salutation;
  }

  public void setSalutation(String salutation) {
      Salutation = salutation;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
     return FirstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
     FirstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
      return LastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      LastName = lastName;
  }

public String getMiddleName() {
    return MiddleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    MiddleName = middleName;
}

public String getNickName() {
    return NickName;
}

 public void setNickName(String nickName) {
     NickName = nickName;
 }


}
```

and then I set up the `interface class` called `PatientInfoAPI`:

```
public interface PatientInfoAPI{

@PATCH("/tables/PatientInformation/{id}")
  public void update(@Body UserUpdate updatedDAta, @Path("id") String  id,Callback<UserUpdate> response);


 }
```

Notice I'm passing the table id to be "PATCH'd", and most importantly I have the `@Body` annotation which allows me to pass the data to the update without getting an error (I tried without it and was getting an error)

And finally inside my main Activity:

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(new OkClient()) //very important!!!
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)//base url
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {//You may not need to pass headers, but I do, so this is how it's done.
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {

                    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", APIUrls.ZUMO_KEY);

                }
            })
            .build();
    PatientInfoAPI patchService = restAdapter.create(PatientInfoAPI.class);

    UserUpdate updatedUser = new UserUpdate();
    updatedUser.setSalutation("Sr.");
    updatedUser.setFirstName("YesSirtItsWorking");
    updatedUser.setLastName("Bays");
    updatedUser.setMiddleName("ComeOn Now man!");
    updatedUser.setNickName("");

     //Passing the tableId along with the data to update
     patchService.update(updatedUser, APIUrls.TABLE_ID, new retrofit.Callback<UserUpdate>() {
        @Override
        public void success(UserUpdate userUpdates, retrofit.client.Response response) {


            Log.v("All is good", "Nickname:" +  userUpdates.getNickName().toString() + " Email: " + userUpdates.getEmailAddress().toString());



        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Log.v("All is good", error.getLocalizedMessage().toString());


        }
    });
```

I know that maybe some of the steps are not very sophisticated, but for those who are starting with Retrofit and OkHttp, and most importantly have been struggling to get `PATCH` to work with Android, this is the solution.  Again, props to @Adam for pretty much guide me through the process.  @Adam was the one who really answered this question - I'm just putting it all together for those who may need a to see the full picture.  Thanks, @Adam!!! You are a rockstar!

Answer (score 4):

As GreyBeardedGeek says, you can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) + [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to implement this.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient())
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .build();
MyPatchService patchService = restAdapter.create(MyPatchService.class);
UserUpdate updatedUser = new UserUpdate();
updatedUser.Salutation = "Mr";
updatedUser.FirstName = "Adam";
patchService.update(updatedUser);
```

And `MyPatchService` looks something like this:

```
public interface MyPatchService {
    @PATCH("/some/update/endpoint")
    User update(UserUpdate updatedObject);
}
```

Your `UserUpdate` class could look like this:

```
public class UserUpdate {
    public String Salutation;
    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
}
```

If you do this, the JSON that will be sent will look like this (note that `LastName` is not serialized since it was never set - this is configurable through supplying a custom [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instance to Retrofit):

```
{
  "Salutation": "Mr",
  "FirstName": "Adam"
}
```

The request/response objects are plain Java representations of the objects you send/receive over the network. Being a patch request, you can make your member vars `Integer`, `Boolean`, etc and they won't get serialized if not set (i.e. if they're `null`).

Comment: Thanks @Adam and  @GreyBeardedGeek for your responses.  So, the JSON object that I am sending as a PATCH, will it be added in the restAdapter object?  Like so `.setPatch(myJsonData)`, or will it be passed inside the interface?  Sorry for the questions: I am new to OkHTTP and Retrofit.  Thanks

Comment: You simply create the request/response objects then write the interface to expect them - Retrofit does all the serialization and deserialization for you. I'll update the example a little further, but I'd recommend [having a good read about the magic that is Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: thanks for your help.  I am now implementing all you have showed here.  One thing:  when you said `User update(UserUpdate updatedObject);` did you mean to say `Userupdate(UserUpdate updatedObject);`  `(UserUpdated(UserUpdated updatedObject);` Correct?

Comment: Nope, it's written as intended - in this example the server returns the full updated object (in this case, a `User` object). I _do not know_ if this is correct behaviour for an endpoint accepting requests with the PATCH verb.

Comment: Ok. My endpoint is going to be `/tables/PatientInformation/my-table-id-here"`, so I am assuming than I would need to have something along these lines:   ` public interface MyPatchService {
    @PATCH("/tables/PatientInformation/my-table-id-here"")
    User PatientInformation(UserUpdate updatedObject);
}`.  Is this what you're saying?  I am very sorry if this is too noobie.

Comment: That's going down the path of explaining how Retrofit works in general, rather than how it works with PATCH. Read the docs; they're short, cover all of this in detail (for example how to specify the ID in that request endpoint via the interface) and do a far better job of explaining the library than getting it piecemeal from me :)

Comment: Thanks @Adam.  Will do. Thanks again, and will make sure to report if/when I get this thing to work :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but apparently, if you use Retrofit with the OkHTTP's OKClient, then Retrofit supports an @Patch annotation.

See http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/PATCH.html and [Retrofit & HTTP Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118929/retrofit-http-patch)

Comment: As of March 2016, with Retrofit 2.0.0-beta4 I am using PATCH successfully without any further libraries inclusion as mentioned in the answers here.